# NullReferenceException when using properties of custom WebViewPage injected by Unity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, dependency-injection, unity-container

I've writen a custom WebViewPage implementation with a couple extra properties that I've annotated like so:

```
[Dependency]
public Tenant CurrentTenant { get; set; }
```

In a view inheriting from this (Shared/_Layout, if it matters), I have a reference to `@CurrentTenant.Name`.

I've written a custom implementation of IViewPageActivator that does this for Create:

```
var obj = this._container.Resolve(type);
return obj;
```

I put a breakpoint here and can see that this is getting called and that the property is getting injected correctly when I inspect `obj`... and yet the page throws an NullReferenceException on my attempt to access properties of CurrentTenant!  What's going on here?

**edit**:  I've found that this behavior is not an issue if I try to inject the information into a "regular" view instead of the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813291/asp-net-mvc-3-dependency-injection-controllers-views-action-filters) had this problem when I understood better what I was looking for.

Anyway, it looks like none of the options here are appealing.  I inserted this into the top of my _Layout.cshtml, but I'd love if someone knew of a better way to do it:

```
@{
  this.CurrentTenant = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer.Resolve<Tenant>(); //and so on
 }
```